# How to modify field in StackedInline?

Tags: python, django

I've to display tags for users and I've used the following code to display tags

```
class TagInline(StackedInline):
    model = Tag.users.through
    extra = 1

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [
        TagInline,
    ]
```

It displays a drop-down list of tags and a link "Add another Tag-User Relationship". Clicking on the link gives another dropdown for tags and this way I can add multiple tags.

My question is that how can I show tags in multi-select instead of dropdown so I can select multiple tags at once.

Answer (score 0):

1. copy file `stacked.html` from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/edit_inline/`
2. past in out directory with saving relative directories (`you_templates_dir/admin/`)
3. edit this template